# regexp to strip empty space in an equation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an equation where the last operator is specified consecutively it should remove the last operator. I amnot sure how to do this using regex

```
i.e
   var operators = ['*', '-', "+'];
   if(operators.indexOf(eql.innerText.slice(-1)) > -1) {
      eqText = eqText.replace(/.$/, '');
   }
```

in this case if my equation is 9 * *, i want it to strip the last * along with the space before it.
basically it should be 9 * instead of 9 * *

any pointers

Answer (score 2):

The below regex would remove the last `-` or `*` or `+` along with the preceding space.,

```
eqText = eqText.replace(/ [-*+]$/, '');
```

OR

Use the below regex to remove one or more spaces preceeding along with the last special characters.

```
eqText = eqText.replace(/ +[-*+]$/, '');
```

Comment: Probably throw a `+` after the space, to handle `9  *    *`

Comment: And I suspect although they didn't ask for it, they probably want any trailing spaces ditched as well. So: `/ +[-*+] *$/`